# Magento 2 | Add custom attribute for orders

Tags: magento2, orders, custom-attributes

I want every order to have a custom attribute called "Fremdnummer".

How can I do that using InstallData? I just know how to add custom customer attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom module and use upgrade schema to add custom attribute in order table

**app/code/Vendor/SalesOrder/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SalesOrder\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quote = 'quote';
        $orderTable = 'sales_order';

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($quote),
                'custom_attribute',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );
        //Order table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'custom_attribute',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't execute when I use setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile

Comment: Do you create it as a separate module and saying that the module is not updating?

Comment: I tried  this, it worked, but looks like it's not visible on admin grid or in filter.